# Docker-CE or docker on CentOS

Tags: docker, centos

I have a group of CentOS 7 machines that I had previously installed 'docker'; however, I'm finding that there's a repo with newer versions for CentOS with the docker repo added:  'docker-ce'.

```
Name        : docker
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 2
Version     : 1.12.6
Release     : 68.gitec8512b.el7.centos
Size        : 15 M
Repo        : extras/7/x86_64

versus
Name        : docker-ce
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 17.12.0.ce
Release     : 1.el7.centos
Size        : 123 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : docker-ce-stable
```

Which would be the preferred version to run?  Newer is better or is the package that ships with CentOS extras the best?  So OS vendor or software vendor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About two years ago Docker changed the way they do versioning and also introduced an entreprise edition of the technology called docker-ee, the open source version was renamed to docker-ce (docker community edition).

So to answer your question if you want to be up to date with the latest releases you should install docker-ce

Comment: Thanks alot.  Now if I could figure out how to upgrade without destroying my containers, I'd be in business... something something Error response from daemon: Unknown runtime specified docker-runc

Comment: @billabongrob did you ever figure out how they are actually different?  I'm getting odd failures on the -ce edition for things that work fine in the plain-docker edition.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is undergoing development at a fast pace. Update to docker-ce-stable.
Since docker 1.12 there have been many updates to docker such as the storage driver, swarm mode bug fixes etc have come in.